# How to reverse range value in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hello everything is working fine but i gave custom range so now it is showing 10,9,8,7,6...1 , i want it from 1,2,3,4,5..10 , i am new to pandas so please help me out

```
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("data.csv")
ConditionData = data.loc[:,['Country/Region','Confirmed']].sort_values(by="Confirmed",ascending=False).head(10)
ConditionData.index = range(10, 0, -1)
print(ConditionData)


    Country/Region  Confirmed
10              US    4290259
9           Brazil    2442375
8            India    1480073
7           Russia     816680
6     South Africa     452529
5           Mexico     395489
4             Peru     389717
3            Chile     347923
2   United Kingdom     301708
1             Iran     293606
```

somebody please help me

Answer (score 2):

You can [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and add 1. This way you do not need to care about the number of rows:

```
ConditionData = ConditionData.reset_index(drop=True)
ConditionData.index += 1
```

*NB. Indexing in python starts from 0, so unless you have a particular need for starting from 1, you might leave it as a zero based range*

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by...

```
ConditionData.index = range(1, 11)
```

Or reverse it with:

```
ConditionData.index = list(range(10, 0, -1))[::-1]
```